# How to push into array in place based on date?

Tags: mongodb

Based on following dataset (limited to 3 entries, but have thousands of entries in reality)

```
{
"data": [
  {
    open: 46.990002,
    high: 55.119999,
    close: 53.16,
    low: 46.860001,
    volume: 3479500,
    date: ISODate("2021-06-28T00:00:00.000Z")
   },      
   {
    open: 50,
    high: 50,
    close: 47.5,
    low: 46.397999,
    volume: 3747400,
    date: ISODate("2021-06-30T00:00:00.000Z")
   }]
}
```

How could I insert this in place and keep the order based on the date not knowing the $position index?

```
{
  open: 54.66,
  high: 57.990002,
  close: 50,
  low: 48.34,
  volume: 3230400,
  date: ISODate("2021-06-29T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

End result needed would be:

```
{
"data":[
{
  open: 46.990002,
  high: 55.119999,
  close: 53.16,
  low: 46.860001,
  volume: 3479500,
  date: ISODate("2021-06-28T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{
  open: 54.66,
  high: 57.990002,
  close: 50,
  low: 48.34,
  volume: 3230400,
  date: ISODate("2021-06-29T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{
 open: 50,
 high: 50,
 close: 47.5,
 low: 46.397999,
 volume: 3747400,
 date: ISODate("2021-06-30T00:00:00.000Z")
}]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working by doing this:

```
var currentTick = {open:66.51, high:70.26, close:67.95, low:66.0006, volume:823548, date:ISODate("2021-10-29 00:00:00")}

db.tmpCollection.updateOne(
    {"symbol":"XYZ"},
    {$push: {
        data: {
            $each: [currentTick],
            $sort: {date: 1}
        }
    }}
)
```

Let me know if you know of a better way. ;-)